# How to lookup a (JDBC) JNDI resource?

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

We have a **personal java library** which is deployed on a tomcat server (v5.5 & v6).
This library is shared with many web applications, so it was deployed on shared/lib in tomcat directory.

Exceptionaly, i have to create a new class into this library which lookup a jdbc datasource via JNDI.

For that, here my code :

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/corp.xx.xx.xxxxDS");
```

All context are instantiated without problem. But when it lookup the jdbc datasource, i have an exception : Name jdbc not Found in Context

We are not in a webapp, is it a problem ?
Is it possible to declare a context.xml with a ResourceLink ? how ?

nb: the jndi is setted in server.xml (a resource in GlobalNamingResources)

Comment: When you write 'pb' do you perhaps mean 'problem'? Please don't treat this place like a mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <ResourceLink name="linkToGlobalResource"
            global="simpleValue"
            type="java.lang.Integer"
  ...
</Context>
```

Where *name* is the new name (name relative to java:comp/env), *global* is the global jndi name configured in server.xml

So, from your code, look up **linkToGlobalResource** which will give you the **linked global resource**

Reference: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Links

**Answer Updated:**

Your JNDI access will be from web-app and not shared jar because standalone jar does not have the concept of context.

Comment: yeah, but i would like to know if it is possible to add the jndi resource into the web context for a shared library. Otherwise, i have to add the context in each web application which used the library :(